# ASP.NET Core Kendo Grid and model

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-grid

I want to set model for kendo grid from property of model.
I try to do the following:

```
                    <div id="donorReport-grid"></div>

                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            if (@Model.Result.Count > 0) {
                                var localDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                                    data: @JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.Result);
                                });
                                $("#donorReport-grid").kendoGrid({
                                    dataSource: localDataSource,
                                    scrollable: true,
                                    columns: [
                                        {
                                            field: "CarrierName",
                                            title: "Test",
                                            width: 150
                                        },

                                    ]
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    </script>
```

but It does not work, I get an error (why so?):

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The collection type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormCollection' on
>   'Tms.Web.Models.DrugConsortium.Reports.DcReportDonorResultModel.Form'
>   is not supported.'

How to set model for kendo grid from Model property? I can't do an ajax request in my case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your data like this :

```js
var myData = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Result));
```

And then set `dataSource` of Grid :

```js
<script>

 $(document).ready(function () {

    var myData = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Result));

    $("#donorReport-grid").kendoGrid({
         dataSource: {
              data: myData ,
              schema: ...
         },
         scrollable: true,
         columns: ...
     });
 });

</script>
```